# Scrolling in EXTjs

Tags: jsp, extjs, scroll

i want to put a scroll bar in my web in EXTjs but the problem is that with autoscroll = true it is not work because if i minimize the window the scroll dissapear...

I think that my problem i s that my web page is in another web page, where i call with window.open...

i paste my code below:

First the call of my web:

```
   window.open("http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTipoPapel?usuario="+document.form1.CLAVEUSU.value,'_parent');
```

Then i paste some part of my jsp code (that included the EXTjs code), the part where i use the autosrcoll.

```
  <script>
        var usuario = "${usuario}";

  Ext.require([
         'Ext.form.*',
         'Ext.form.field.File',
         'Ext.layout.container.Column',
         'Ext.window.MessageBox',
         'Ext.fx.target.Element',
         'Ext.panel.*',
         'Ext.toolbar.*',
         'Ext.button.*',
         'Ext.grid.*',
         'Ext.container.ButtonGroup',
         'Ext.layout.container.Table',
         'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager'
     ]);

     Ext.onReady(function() {
         Ext.QuickTips.init();


         var top = Ext.widget({
             xtype: 'form',
             id: 'multiColumnForm',
             collapsible: true,
             frame: true,
             autoScroll: true,
             //renderer:contenedor,
             title: 'TABLAS DE LOTES - MANTENIMIENTO',
             bodyPadding: '0 0 0',
             width: '80%',
             //height: 800,
             fieldDefaults: {
                 labelAlign: 'side',
                 msgTarget: 'side'
             },
             items: [tuUsuario,cabeceraPrueba,filtradoGrupo,customGroup,
             simpleCombo,mensajesGroup],

             //controlFechas

             buttons: [{
                 text: 'Altas',
                 hidden: true,
                 handler: function() {
                     this.up('form').getForm().isValid();
                 }
             },{
                 text: 'Consulta pendientes de imprimir',
                 disabled: true,
                 id:'botonConsulta',
                 handler: function() {
                    consultarTipoPapel();
                 }
             },{
                 text: 'Consulta ya impresos',
                 disabled: true,
                 id:'botonConsultaSimple',
                 handler: function() {
                    consultarTipoPapelSimple();
                 }
             },{

                 text: 'Modificar',
                 disabled: true,
                 id:'botonModificar',
                 handler: function() {
                     modificarRegistro();
                 }
             },{
                 text: 'Limpiar',
                 handler: function() {
                     limpiarCampos();
                 }
             }]
         });

         top.render(document.body);

     });
```

Comment: The context and description of your problem is not clear. I think it would be best if you put a full example somewhere for people to look at.

Comment: Thanks for all, i solved the problem open my app in a new window and not in the frame inside the web app, finally it was a problem of the original app. In a new window a dont have problems, thanks for all again.